# google speech api received RST_STREAM with error code 2

Tags: c#, api, speech

The code in c#:

```
namespace GoogleSpeechConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var speech = SpeechClient.Create();

            var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Flac,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = "en",
            }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile("myAudioFile.flac"));
            foreach (var result in response.Results)
            {
                foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tried all kinds of formats and settings like raw, wave and flac. But no luck.
I get the same error in CloudSpeechGrpc.cs in following function:

```
  public virtual global::Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.RecognizeResponse Recognize(global::Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.RecognizeRequest request, grpc::CallOptions options)
  {
    return CallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall(__Method_Recognize, null, options, request);
  }
```

and the following error:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Received
>   RST_STREAM with error code 2")'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is why am I getting the following error:

Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Received RST_STREAM with error code 2")'

in all kinds of formats and settings.

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve it?